# Shifting elements in an array to the right by 1

Tags: c

I am having trouble figuring out how to properly shift elements in an array to the right by 1.  The array is inialized to be `[1 ,2, 3, 4, 5]`. So when I shift, result should be `[2, 3, 4, 5, 1]`, but it comes out as `[2, 3, 4, 5, 0]`, and i am not sure why. Here is what i have so far -

```
   for(k = 0; k <= n - 1; k++){
   array[k] = array[k+1];
   }

   printf("Array is now:\n");
   k = 0;
   while(k < n) {
       printf("x[%d] = %f\n", k, array[k]);
       k++;
   }
```

the result prints vertically.

Comment: You don't save a copy of the first element. And you read out of the array bounds when `k` is `n-1`, because `k+1 == n - 1 + 1 == n`, so `array[n]` in all.

Comment: I suggest you write appropriate functions, which interpret the array as shifted. Actually shifting elements becomes expensive for large arrays. If they're guaranteed to be comparably small, you're free to go with whatever works, though.

Comment: Compiler warning C4477: 'printf' : format string '%f' requires an argument of type 'double', but variadic argument 2 has type 'int'. I *assumed* `array` was `int`, please supply the MCVE.

Comment: @BadProgrammer  You are trying to write code that shifts elements to the left instead of to the right.

Comment: The operation you show is usually described as 'rotate right'.

Answer (score 1):

I know it's an old question, but I think it is useful to provide a complete code for the task of shifting an array's elements *to the right* by 1.
One idea is to start by the end and replace each element with its left neighbor. Since at first, we overwrite the end element, we will save it and put it in its final place at the first slot after the loop.

[image]

Code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

void rotate_right(int* a, const int n) {
    if (n < 1) return;
    const int temp = a[n - 1];
    for (int i = n - 1; i > 0; i--) {
        a[i] = a[i - 1];
    }
    a[0] = temp;
}

int main() {
    int a[] = { 1 , 2, 3, 4, 5 };
    const int n = sizeof(a) / sizeof(a[0]);

    rotate_right(a, n);

    for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i) {
        printf("%d ", a[i]);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a basic code for right shift by 1 only. if you want a general code that can work with any index to right shift, I would suggest use a variable.

```
//array elements are from index 0 to n-1

int tempData  = array[0]; // if right shift is only by 1
for(k = 0; k < n-1; k++){
   array[k] = array[k+1];
}

array[n-1] = tempData; //reinstall the value of first index to last index
printf("Array is now:\n");
k = 0;
while(k < n) {
    printf("x[%i] = %d\n", k, array[k]);
    k++;
}
```

Comment: This still *reads* from out-of-bounds array, which might cause a fault. I suggest `k < n-1`

Comment: `array[n-1] = tempData;` ----> `array[k] = tempData;`

Comment: Based on optimization option can be different.... BTW the concept is that you do not need another subtraction if already has a ready-to-use index...